# serialize() outputting the same as datastring but not working as ajax data value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've got a form set up with 4 input fields *(login, email, password, password again)* when I click submit it validates the input and sends it to *process-register.php* via *GET*.

Now here's the problem when I use the *data* variable as *ajax data* it all works perfectly fine but if I use *$("form").serialize()* it doesn't work anymore...

*EDIT*: It doen't pass the variables to process-register.php

I've outputted both strings with *document.write* and they are **exactly** the same!!!
How is this possible?! Please help me fix this...

```
var data = 'login=' + login.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&pass=' + pass.val() + '&confirmpass='  + confirmpass.val();

    //document.write($("form").serialize());  --> The output is
    //document.write(data);                   --> exactly the same! :O

    $('input').attr('disabled','true');

    $('.loading').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "process-register.php", 

        type: "GET",

        data: data,                  //--> works!            
        data: $("form").serialize(), //--> doesn't work!

        cache: false,

        success: function (echo) {
        //success code...
        }       
    });
```

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work". What is the final url of your ajax request? Are there *any* query string parameters?

Comment: Maybe a difference in whitespace or other HTML special characters, which may not be apparent when you use `document.write()`. Try `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Note that `serialize()` will call `encodeURIComponent`, which you're not doing when you create `data` by hand. This deals with special characters properly.

Comment: Updated "it doesn't work" -> the variables aren't passed to php

Comment: No it isn't.. And console.log also returns the *exact* same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line `$('input').attr('disabled','true');` to after serializing the data.
Like below.

```
var data  = $("form").serialize();
$('input').attr('disabled',true);

$.ajax({
  url: "process-register.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: data    
});
```

**From API Documentation** (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Note: Only "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

**It will not serialize `disabled` controls also**

Comment: Good catch. After I posted my answer, I realized that I'd misread which form wasn't working, and my answer no longer made sense.

Comment: This worked but why if the 2 strings are the same, one works and the other doesn't?